# Named vs anonymous functions different behavior with a promise

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I ran into a bug which I finally solved, but why it happen(ed/s) is still beyond me.

I save a variable `foo` using [`browser.storage.local.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get) for a firefox addon that I'm developing. I know that the variable is set, and the apparent bug was relying on some small piece of code that leads to this:

```js
browser.storage.local.get((val) => {
  if (val['foo'] === undefined){
    console.log('Undefined');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Defined')
  }
});
// Outputs `Defined`, which is correct.
```

However, if I define the callback first, and then I get wrong output.

```js
function checkStoredSettings(val) {
  if (val['foo'] === undefined) {
    console.log('Undefined')
  }
  else {
    console.log("Defined")
  }
}

browser.storage.local.get().then(checkStoredSettings, console.log);
// Outputs `Undefined`, which is incorrect.

//UPDATE
browser.storage.local.get(checkStoredSettings);
// Outputs `Undefined`, which is also incorrect.
```

Can someone explain what am I not getting here? I have now run the above two codes sequentially (in both orders) in the same scope.

Comment: Have you tried this? `browser.storage.local.get(checkStoredSettings)` Your first example has the callback inside `get`, not inside `then`

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong copy paste in my update. So yes, I did try that too. Also, I'm surprised that this signature even works `browser.storage.local.get(function)` because the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get) rules out such a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like that ?

```
browser.storage.local.get('foo').then(console.log)
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But I'm still not satisfied why it doesn't work for the one way in the original question, while it works for the other one.

Comment: From the documentation :

"Caution: When used within a content script in Firefox versions prior to 52, the Promise returned by browser.storage.local.get() is fulfilled with an Array containing one Object. The Object in the Array contains the keys found in the storage area, as described above."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get#return_value

Comment: try to console.log val[0].foo